# Breakpoints ignored on server code VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a react app with express as the back end server. However, any breakpoint that I add on my server code is being ignored and displaying as Unverified breakpoint but the breakpoint on client code is working.
My current launch.json is as follows:

```
{
  "type": "chrome",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Chrome",
  "url": "http://localhost:4001",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
  "breakOnLoad": true,
  "sourceMaps": true,
},
```

My folder structure looks like this:
[image]

Comment: I followed this https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21363
However even adding the configurations as demoed has not worked till now.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're debugging your client, not your server.

You need another configuration to debug your server, something that will start the server within VS Code and debug that.

You should add to your `launch.json` something like this:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Server debug",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/server.js"
},
```

Where `server.js` should be replaced by the name of you node express server.

Obviously you need to stop your currently running server, before launching the debugger.

You could probably also attach to the running server process, but I find that a bit more annoying.